# C++ socket - wstring to Java socket

Tags: java, android, c++, string, sockets

I've got a server with a custom protocol (for instant messaging - the protocol is already in place on the desktop client) and I'm trying implement it on an Android app currently.

I've managed to open the socket to the server and send a single 4-byte integer, however, I cannot get Java to send a string or receive (properly) a string from the server.

The server is written in C++ and hosted on a Windows machine, and it uses a wstring for communication (to allow non-ASCII characters to be sent). How can I go about getting the app to read/write to the socket in the correct format? I believe a wstring, in this usage, should be a UTF-16 string, but I'm not sure about the endian-ness.

So far, this is the Java code (I've disabled the NetworkOnMainThread exception for the time being, while testing):

```
private String recv_from_server() {
    String ret = "";
    char[] bytes = new char[8192];
    try {

        int in = sinput.read(bytes, 0, 8192);
        if(in > 0) {
            byte[] str = bytes.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            ret = new String(str, "UTF-8");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {}
    return ret;
}


private void send_to_server(String message) {
    try {
        soutput.write(message);
        soutput.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.chat_message_message)).setText(ex.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    refresh();
    refresher = new Timer();
    refresher.schedule(new RefresherEvt(), 15000);
    if(open_connection() == true) {
        String ret = "";
        while(ret == "") {
            ret = recv_from_server();
        }
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.chat_message_message)).setText(ret);
        send_to_server("test message");
    }
}
```

I get garbage data from the recv_from_server function and the send function doesn't seem to ever reach the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show the C++ code for sending and receiving or a tcp dump to give us an idea of what the Java program is supposed to receive and send.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
byte[] str = bytes.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
ret = new String(str, "UTF-8");
```

will just return a string of the form `"[B@nnnnnn"`, because `char[]` doesn't override `Object.toString().` The double conversion doesn't accomplish anything useful either. 
And of course the `char[]` array should be called `chars`, not `bytes`. It should be:

```
return new String(chars, 0, in, "UTF-8"); // or UTF-16 or whatever you determine
```

I assume that `sinput` is a `BufferedReader` around the input stream? Otherwise your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

**First:** The name of this variable definitely is confusing

```
char[] bytes = new char[8192];
```

it's and array of char called bytes which under JAVA definitely isn't the same thing.

**Second:** I don't know which kind of stream you are using here. Some may read char directly some may internally translate from UTF-8 to UTF-16 etc...etc..

```
int in = sinput.read(bytes, 0, 8192);
```

But **Third:** This doesn't do anything as far as I can tell:

```
byte[] str = bytes.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
ret = new String(str, "UTF-8");
```

You assume you have a valid String in `bytes` (which are actually chars) and translate it to a byte array (which is called str) in UTF-8 encoding. Then you translate it back from UTF-8 to the JAVA internal UTF-16 encoding in `ret`. Why not Just return `bytes.toString()` ?

**One Possibility**

You say the strings in the C-Code are wstring aka. based on UTF-16 or UCS2. for Windows as far as I know. So one assumption would be that the data you receive is UTF-16 encoded and if it's actually UCS2 you will still cover all characters in the BMP. So the first thing I would try is to directly decode it from UTF-16 like:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
// Actually read bytes -- don't know
// if your stream can handle that
int n sinput.read(bytes,0,BUFFERSIZE);
// silently assume n % 2 == 0 and UTF-16 doesn't use surrogates
String str = new String(bytes,n,"UTF16-BE" /*"UTF16-LE"*/);
```

**However**

The std::wstring format most of the time is only used for **internal** representations of strings since for most characters you have one string position for one character. You do not have to fight with variable length encodings. Thats fully true for UCS4 and almost true for UTF-16. That gives it a great advantage internally. 
But for the external representation aka. File or Internet UTF-8 is the lingua franca since it is compact, doesn't care for endianess and ASCII is still visible as ASCII without any interspersed zero bytes.. and much more.

So even without seeing the C-Code I would still assume that the external representation has a good chance of being UTF-8. In that case you would simply have to do:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
// Actually read bytes -- don't know
// if your stream can handle that
sinput.read(bytes,0,BUFFERSIZE);
String str = new String(bytes,BUFFERSIZE,"UTF8");
```

For your soutput.write(...) you also would have to call getBytes("UTF8")